# How to keep the image aspect ratio when resize?

Tags: imagemagick, magickwand

For example, when I only provide one of the `length` or `width` parameters, another parameter is automatically calculated while maintaining the aspect ratio of the image.

Is there a related function in the `MagicWand` library? Still have to calculate the aspect ratio yourself?

Comment: https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php and https://imagemagick.org/MagickWand/resize.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a related function in the MagicWand library? Still have to calculate the aspect ratio yourself?

When working with MagickWand C-API, you would be expected to calculate the aspect ratio yourself. There *was* `MagickTransformImage` method that supports both cropping & resizing by evaluating a formatted string (including aspect ratios), but that has been deprecated & removed.

In the `MagickCore` library, there's [ParseMetaGeometry](https://imagemagick.org/www/api/MagickCore/geometry_8c.html#a1abe3eb98960bbdde8e8ef40e2c29b69) method that will support formatted string w/ aspect ratio flags.